# C# WinForms Selecting ComboBox item in new form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need a little help. I have a main form named `Form1`. 
When I click the button `btn1`, a new form named `Form2` appears. 
In the `Form2`, I have a couple of TextBoxes and a ComboBox named `cb2`.

For the TextBoxes, I set the displayed text in this way:

```
//on Form1 I have this code
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2= new Form2();
    string a = "Text to be displayed in a textBox";
    form2.txtMyTextBox = a;

    form2.Owner = this;
    form2.ShowDialog(this);
}

//on Form2 I set Public String
public string txtMyTextBox
{
    get { return txt1.Text; }
    set { txt1.Text = value; }
}
```

How do I set the selected item in my ComboBox drop down menu? I tried in the same way used in the TextBoxes, but it does not work.

```
//Tried for combobox 
public string myCb2
{
    get { return cb2.Text; }
    set { cb2.SelectedValue = value; }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your approach?

Comment: With my initial approach, combobox vas empty (no item selected). I used MD.unicorn's solution and it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose the `SelectedIndex` property of the ComboBox in a property of the form:

```
public int MySelectedIndex // user a more appropriate name
{
    get { return cb2.SelectedIndex; }
    set { cb2.SelectedIndex = value; }
}
```

This gives you only the index. If you need the text of the selected item, you need to use `SelectedItem`:

```
public string MySelectedItem // user a more appropriate name
{
    get { return cb2.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
}
```

I used the `ToString()` method because the type of the `SelectedItem` is object. The underlying type could be anything, according to the objects you filled in the `Items` property of the ComboBox. If you put strings inside, you get strings back, and then you can just use a cast:

```
public string MySelectedItem // user a more appropriate name
{
    get { return (string)cb2.SelectedItem; }
    set { return cb2.SelectedItem = value; }
}
```

Comment: I used the 3rd option you suggested and it works. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. But remember, it only works if your items are of type `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `SelectedIndex` and assign it to Index of the `value` in the `Items` Collection:

```
set { cb2.SelectedIndex = cb2.Items.IndexOf(value); }
```

Comment: It this works (which means the `value` exists in the `Items` collection), the he can just use `cb2.SelectedItem = value;`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to Pass / Set Data to the Form Initially, is to Create a Constructor which set these values to the controls.

```
public Form2(string initText, object selectedValue) {
    this.txtMyTextBox.Text = initText;
    this.cb2.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
}
```

another way is to Expose/create Public properties that work on Controls, if the values to send are more..

Comment: I understand the benefit of passing values in a constructor, but since I have to pass more than 15 values to Form2, I didn't go that route. But will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding better way will be pass value in constructor of Form2 and set the values of controls in From2_Load event and for combobox set it's itemsouce than set selected value(ensure that itemsouce contain selected value and both have same intance.)